# How to reduce select commands in a Simple one table query. Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am firing the following query inside a loop  to get the id from a table named 'cup' with few conditions in the where clause, now my problem is.. it fires lakhs of select queries

```
 cup_ids = Cup.where(deleted: false, temporary: false, archived: false, website_id: website.id, junior_report: true).select(:id)
```

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I want to change the query so that I can reduce the time consumption by the select command..... just like eager loading there at least we need two tables here it is one table, is there any way so that I can reduce firing select query to DB

Comment: Did you call this query in a loop or something?

Comment: yes it is inside a loop

Comment: The above query only results a single select statement. That is 

    "select cup.id from cup where cup.deleted = false, cup.temporary: false ...... "
The lakhs of query results because your loop runs that much time.

Comment: thank you for repeating my problem statement @a_k_v i wil edit it

Comment: What's the loop? Try adding enough and detailed information to replicate your problem, otherwise, your question won't get enough attention and/or will be closed because it _"needs details or clarity"_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pluck`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck):

```
cup_ids = Cup.where(deleted: false, temporary: false, archived: false, website_id: website.id, junior_report: true).pluck(:id)
```

Comment: thank you currenlty my query goes like this       cup_ids = Cup.where(deleted: false, temporary: false, archived: false, website_id: website.id, junior_report: true).where.not(id: nil).pluck(:id)